# Where to find Google Apps package for AOSP built images?

Tags: android, android-source

I just built and installed the JB AOSP image for my Galaxy Nexus, following Google's instruction here:
http://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html

However, the image does nto come with Google apps, like Navigation and Play Store. How can I get these apps on to my device?

Comment: Google doesn't supply those in AOSP as they are Google's own applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your phone is rooted you can download the zip file and install it via the recovery:
[Latest GAPPS Download](http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-jb-20121011-signed.zip)

Comment: @selshin thx thx thx... struggled a lot for google apps in aosp